# How can i change Ornagehrm theme

Tags: php, css, styles, themes, orangehrm

I installed **Orangehrm** System from  [OrnageHRM](http://www.orangehrm.com)
There are two directories called `themes`

`/symfony/web/themes`

`/themes`

How i can change theme of system ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change theme of OrangeHRMS than you should change in following path of themes folder

```
/symfony/web/webres_554af33274f2b9.68269152/themes
```

Here you will get two folder inside themes
1. default
2. smackgreen

Now you need to go in default folder and you will get css folder in this and there is also main.css

You need change in main.css file for change theme of OrangeHRMS.

I Hope your problem will solve.